# Why is the sourceBuffer failing to appendBuffer?

Tags: javascript, video-streaming, streaming, buffer, mp4

I'm not sure what I've missed here. Can anyone help me figure out why the appendBuffer is failing? I've set up an event listener for the error but it doesn't appear to give very helpful information.

```
            const videoElement = document.getElementById("vid1");
            const mediaSource = new MediaSource();
            videoElement.src = URL.createObjectURL(mediaSource);

            let sourceBuffer;

            mediaSource.addEventListener('sourceopen', () => {
                sourceBuffer = mediaSource.addSourceBuffer('video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E,mp4a.40.2"');

                sourceBuffer.addEventListener('error', function(event) {
                    console.error('Error occurred while appending buffer:', event);
                });

                fetch('http://localhost:3000/dashTest')
                    .then(response => response.arrayBuffer())
                    .then(buffer => {
                        const file = new Uint8Array(buffer);
                        const chunkSize = 10 * 1024 * 1024; // 10 MB
                        let offset = 0;

                        const appendChunks = async () => {
                            // console.log(mediaSource.readyState, sourceBuffer.updating, offset < file.length);
                            if (mediaSource.readyState === 'open' && !sourceBuffer.updating && offset < file.length) {
                                const chunk = file.slice(offset, offset + chunkSize);
                                const chunkBlob = await new Blob([chunk], { type: 'video/mp4' });//.arrayBuffer();
                                const chunkUrl = URL.createObjectURL(chunkBlob);
                                console.log(mediaSource.readyState);
                                //ISSUE: this append is failing
                                sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(chunk)
                                offset += chunkSize;
                            } else if (offset >= file.length) {
                                console.log('end of stream');
                                mediaSource.endOfStream();
                            }
                        };

                        // add event listener for updateend event
                        sourceBuffer.addEventListener('updateend', async () => {
                            await appendChunks();
                        });

                        // call appendChunks to start appending data
                        appendChunks();
                    });
            });
```

Comment: Is your accessed file (by fetch command) actually a "fragmented MP4"? I haven't tested your code but it alone could be fine, and the real problem is maybe that the MP4 file type is wrong? You cannot use a regular MP4, it must be in chunked format.

Comment: @VC.One Thanks I really appreciate the response. Hmm no, I am sending just a plain mp4. Do you have any resources you could point to to make videos into 'chunked format'?

Comment: You need an encoding tool. Download one for your OS. I use Windows so my options are FFmpeg (on command line) or HandBrake (with user interface).